# ruby not executing from terminal correctly

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, platypus

I have the following ruby script:

```
require "rubygems"
require "rest-client" #although not required in the program
require "open-uri"
require "nokogiri"


puts "Opening file"
page=File.open("file.html","r"){|file| file.read}
puts page
    page = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
    puts page.class
    #Filters content of page to select all references to the documents filing date
    td_rows = page.css('td i.blue')
    puts td_rows
```

I can run this script from CodeRunner or TextWrangler and invoke it from the terminal using ruby 'filename'.  However, I am trying to get the script to run at a certain point in time and have tried calling the script using Keyboard Maestro or Platypus but although it runs it does not seem to complete the line

```
td_rows = page.css('td i.blue')
```

The variable td_rows contains nothing.  Does anyone have any idea why this will not work?

Many thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear about how it's not working?  Does it run fine from the terminal?  Does the script not run at all or is it just the "td_rows = page.css('td i.blue') line that's not working?  Are there any errors when you run from the terminal?

Comment: Are you sure that it's running in the same directory as file.html when invoked by your tools?

Comment: It runs perfectly from the terminal, however, if I run it via keyboard maestro or platypus, the script executes its puts that the "page" variable is a nokogiri element but it does not update the variable td_rows.  The ruby script is not in the same directory as the HTML file but that it works running it from the terminal so I would expect it to run when called from keyboard maestro.

Comment: After running your code, not from the terminal, but from Keyboard Maestro or Platypus, do you see the output from the `puts page` statement?

Comment: yes the puts page does show output when run from both Platypus or KM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out why the nokogiri parse was not working.

For some reason, if the page was opened from the web, the script would work but if the web page was saved to disk first and then opened it did not.  I found that when the page was opened from disk it encountered a nokogiri error and only read and parsed the first few lines of the file.  The error was due to a html comment not being closed on the same line but on a subsequent line.

I managed to overcome this problem by reading the file with the mode "rb" instead of just "r".  i.e. if I replace the file.open line with:

```
page=File.open("file.html","rb"){|file| file.read}
```

nokogiri correctly parses the file.

Answer (score 0):

If your code can't read the file, Nokogiri will still create an empty HTML document when attempting to parse an empty string:

```
[2] (pry) main: 0> Nokogiri::HTML('')
=> #(Document:0x245962c {
  name = "document",
  children = [ #(DTD:0x24ab210 { name = "html" })]
  })
[3] (pry) main: 0> Nokogiri::HTML('').to_html
=> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n\n"
```

And, at that point you will get a Nokogiri::HTML document when you look at its class:

```
[4] (pry) main: 0> Nokogiri::HTML('').class
=> Nokogiri::HTML::Document
```

So checking for the class name in `puts page.class` doesn't do you any good. And, looking for the cells will return empty:

```
[3] (pry) main: 0> Nokogiri::HTML('').css('td i.blue')
=> []
```

Personally, if you want to know if you read the document, look to see if you got any characters:

```
abort("Got nothing") if page.empty?
```

instead of printing the contents or looking at the document.class.

Also, I'd use `page = File.read('file.html')` instead of the `File.open`, but that's just me.

This all points to the file not being found or it being empty. You could use something like `File.exists?('file.html')` to look for its existence and `File.size('file.html')` to check to see if it has contents before continuing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I think the document is being read as the "puts page" outputs the page as expected.

Comment: Well, since we have no idea what is in the "file.html" file, we can't help you with your CSS accessor.

Comment: I don't understand why the file.html is particularly relevant as the code works if run from terminal but not if run from KM or Platypus.  But in case it makes a big difference the url of a similar file is:[url](http://searchwww.sec.gov/EDGARFSClient/jsp/EDGAR_MainAccess.jsp?search_text=%22agreement%20and%20plan%20of%20merger%22%20AND%20%22tender%20offer%22&sort=Date&formType=1&isAdv=true&stemming=false&numResults=100&fromDate=03/14/2012&toDate=03/15/2012&numResults=100)

Comment: It's significant because if the document didn't contain a `<td><i class="blue">` or your accessor was wrong, we'd be wasting our time trying to help. Do you have multiple Ruby instances running on your system? If so, is the same instance being launched in the various ways you are testing the code? You're running on Mac OS, and it uses slight-of-hand to pass environment information to apps so the path might be different.

Comment: The reason I didn't think it was significant is because the code works when run from terminal and therefore, the file must contain the relevant accessor.  I do have multiple instances of Ruby but I have checked that both the KM and terminal are running the same versions of both Ruby and Nokogiri.